# Facebook Logon not working properly with Azure Mobile Client in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm implementing Facebook Logon with Azure Mobile Client in Xamarin.Forms. In iOS, after entering login name and password, it directed to the confirmation page but I couldn't click anything on the screen. The loading icon kept running and should represent that the loading hadn't completed yet. Anyone encountered similar situation and anything I could do to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are/were issues with Facebook auth on Azure App Service due to a deprecation in the Facebook side of the OAuth dance.  See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/397f6952-57bf-4c28-b383-6bba08d28f9a/facebook-login-failures-with-app-service-authentication-authorization?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview for more details.